# A qué se debe la diferencia tan grande entre resultados de Date.now() y Date.UTC()

Tags: javascript

si Date.now() retorna la fecha actual en milisegundos y Date.UTC() la fecha introducida en milisegundos, esta operación ¿no tendria que regresar 86.400.000? mas o menos. porque devuelve una diferencia tan grande?, que estoy haciendo mal?

```
Date.UTC(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, millisec)

Date.UTC(2017,3,11,10,00,00,0000)-Date.now()
2767788547

new Date(Date.now()+2767788547)
Date 2017-04-11T10:00:47.110Z
```

Answer (score 4):

Los meses son zero-based en javascript, mientras que los días y años parten del 1.

```
Date.UTC(1970,0,1)/86400000
// Arroja 0

Date.UTC(1970,1,1)/86400000
// Arroja 31
```

Es un "vicio" que está ahí desde que hicieron el primer draft de javascript, y algunos tipos parecen inconsistentes porque trataron de parecerse a java. La justificación es que javascript se hizo en 10 días. Poco más que la tierra.

Este comportamiento, y el hecho de que siempre se refiera a fecha UTC y no a fecha local, ha generado muchos hilos de preguntas y más de un bug en los últimos 20 años.

Ref: 
[Date UTC is off by a Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507619/javascript-date-utc-function-is-off-by-a-month)